# Print all glyphs for a font in MS Word

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

For some automated tests I need to create a Word Doc that contains all the glyphs of a font (for several different fonts).  Is there an easy way to create a macro that loops through all the available glyphs in a font (and inserts them into a doc)?

Comment: Please edit your question and replace character with glyph. Fonts do not contain characters but glyphs.

Comment: For some reason I can't add a new answer to this question. Probably because it's almost a decade old lol. Anyways, I couldn't find a way to do this, so I made a program that does it: https://github.com/JimmyCushnie/Font-Character-Lister

Answer (score 1):

Geez... I've made something like that a long time ago... Yes, it's possible to do it.

A good start is the [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209205)

---

**Edited to add:**

I knew I had done something like this before. Going through some of my old emails I found a macro I've sent to a friend of mine containing exactly this. Here it is:

```
Sub GenerateFontCatalog()
'
' Macro created in 05/14/2008 by Paulo Santos
'
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim fnt As String
Dim doc As Document
Dim fnts() As String

'*
'* Get all font names
'*
Word.StatusBar = "Reading Font Names..."
ReDim fnts(Word.FontNames.Count)
For i = 1 To Word.FontNames.Count
    fnts(i) = Word.FontNames.Item(i)
    DoEvents
Next

'*
'* Sort alphabetically
'*
Word.StatusBar = "Sorting Font Names..."
For i = 1 To UBound(fnts)
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(fnts)
        If (fnts(i) > fnts(j)) Then
            fnt = fnts(i)
            fnts(i) = fnts(j)
            fnts(j) = fnt
        End If
    Next
    DoEvents
Next

Word.StatusBar = "Generating Font Catalog..."

Set doc = Application.Documents.Add()
doc.Activate

'*
'* Page configuration
'*
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2)
End With

For i = 1 To UBound(fnts)
    '*
    '* Write font name
    '*
    Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Selection.Font.Size = 10
    If (i > 1) Then
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.KeepTogether = False
        Selection.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = False
        Selection.TypeParagraph
    End If
    Selection.TypeText fnts(i)
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = True
    Selection.TypeParagraph

    '*
    '* Write font sample
    '*
    Selection.Font.Name = fnts(i)
    Selection.Font.Size = 16
    Selection.TypeText "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" & Chr(11)
    Selection.TypeText "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" & Chr(11)
    Selection.TypeText "0123456789"
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.KeepTogether = True

    DoEvents
Next

'*
'* Adjust cursor position
'*
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

Word.StatusBar = "Generating Font Index..."
For i = 1 To UBound(fnts)
    Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Selection.Font.Size = 10
    Selection.TypeText fnts(i) & vbTab
    Selection.Font.Name = fnts(i)
    Selection.TypeText "ABC abc 123"
    Selection.TypeParagraph
Next

'*
'* Split the document in two columns
'*
With Selection.Sections(1).PageSetup.TextColumns
    .SetCount NumColumns:=2
    .EvenlySpaced = True
    .LineBetween = False
End With
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=True
Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=Selection.Sections(1).PageSetup.TextColumns(1).Width, Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Word.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really need a list of fonts but a list of all characters in a font.

Comment: Nice macro (even though it doesn't exactly what the requestor wanted in this particular case) - thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why it needs to be in Word? Is this simply to visualize all the characters of a font? If so, you can use Font Book in OS X and go to Print, select Report Type: Repetoire, and save out to PDF.

Edit: Seems I missed "automated tests". Disregard.

Answer (score 1):

Programs like MS Word won't be able to tell you what characters are available in a font.  As far as I can tell you from experience, only the Window's "Character Map" application can show you.  Character Map can be found in your Start menu via Accessories, or alternatively by Start, Run..., and typing "charmap" but there's no convenient method to collect these characters from Character Map or MS Word.

Strictly in Word, I have no idea if it's possible, but since you can execute scripts in Word, I'm sure it's possible to read the font files and read their binary data to collect the available characters inside it.. that's the long-winded way, and possibly the only way to get what you desire.

I've not been able to find a suitable program online to do this for me either, sorry.

Comment: You start Character Map, pick the font you want to use. Then hit Enter and arrow key for each glyph. Once they're all in the field, you hit "Copy" and simply paste them into your word document.

Comment: @BautaBear Blast from the past lol, that was 9 years ago, I'm certain Character Map back in the days didn't do very well to collect all the available glyphs in a font, it only worked with some ranges but left a lot out (the Unicode standard has changed A LOT since then) but I honestly don't know how well it works now. My understanding of the font file format is that it's not at all simple to get a complete list of supported glyphs, the format is garbage really.

Comment: I just had this issue the other day, so the question and its solution are apparently still relevant today.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pretty good compromise is to create an html file with &#XXX; entries for each character and then open that with MS Word.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It sounds like perfectly acceptable solution, especially because you can't get to the list of characters in Word.

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice idea to insert

> The quick brown fox jumps over the
>   lazy dog

and loop through the fonts that need to be tested using a macro.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog can viewed for more details